# How to get selected text from PDF opened in Chrome Browser from an extension

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, text, copy-paste

I have PDF opened in Chrome's new tab and want to copy text. Is there any solution to do this?

Comment: This seems to be a bug with the built-in chrome pdf viewer.  I experience this constantly.  The only work around seems to be download/save the PDF to your local filesystem and open with a different PDF viewer (e.g. preview on mac or acrobat).  Not sure if you can easily turn off the built in chrome PDF viewer to force download, but this issue annoys me constantly.  And no, these are not special PDFs with images of text or copy protection enabled.

Comment: Nowadays chrome should be able to let you do this. If it doesn't it may be because the file is protected.

Comment: I second @mattpr: this is a bug in Chrome. You can also copy the URL and open it in FireFox or other browser.

Comment: See this question on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/853896/copy-text-out-of-a-pdf-file-shown-in-pdf-viewer-in-chrome-web-browser

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this, but it wasn't an issue with Chrome. PDF files allow you to implement some password protected features, such as limiting the ability to copy and paste the content. You can see what these permissions are by opening the file in Adobe Acrobat Reader, and selecting `file -> properties -> Security`. (Chrome's PDF viewer is pretty bare-bones, so I don't know any way to view the permissions with Chrome). But Chrome does enforce the security placed on PDF files.

Fortunately, it is pretty easy to remove password protection from a PDF file. Googling it will provide some online resources that will do it. If you want to do it yourself, here is one option (probably only for advanced users): https://github.com/hhrutter/pdfcpu

Another option for PDFs that are password protected but do not prohibit printing is to simply open the PDF and print it to a PDF file. The new file will not contain any protections.

Answer (score -3):

1. In Chrome, type chrome://plugins/ into the address bar.
2. Look for the Adobe Reader entry in the plug-ins list.
3. Tick the "Always Allowed" box for Adobe Reader.
4. Possibly optional step: Click "Disable" for "Chrome PDF Viewer"

Using all four steps, You can now highlight and copy text from a PDF opened in Chrome, and paste it into another file or document.  (I haven't tried copying images.)

Comment: There is no Adobe Reader entry in the plug-ins list.